# load all json files from a folder

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm searching for a possibility of loading not one specific or named file, but every file from one specified folder in Angular.

Usually I do:

```
this._http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/world/cities/myJsonFile.json').subscribe((data: JsonModel) => {
  console.log('', data);   
});
```

but in a moment of immaculate brain fart, I rendered ~400 cities of my map.component in 30 different .jsons. Now I don't want to name every single json by its name.

So I'm looking for something like this:

```
this._http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/world/cities/').subscribe((data: Array<JsonModel>) => {
  console.log('', data);   
});
```

ps: don't mind the hard-coded localhost, I'm not actually gonna end up using this function. I just want to have a backup to populate my database

Comment: You would need to implement that on your server. For instance if no filename is given, the server should read all files in the data directory and add the contents to an array.

Comment: As stated here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/anj08r/getting_the_list_of_all_files_and_folder_inside/ it is pretty complicated, so I ended up doing a footwork workaround. As said, this is a one-time-only functionality, so I ended up using the microsofts shell command `dir /w` - copied that into vsCode, used the multiselect, and added the http.get onto every line. Not pretty, but it got the job done. Thank you derpirscher for the hint. Turns out, a front-end framework normally does not have/require file-system access (hence the angular HttpClient workaround, I assume)